# R.matlab package error

Tags: r, matlab, package

I'm a Matlab user.  I am trying to get a matrix in Matlab (saved as a *.mat file) into R as a variable.  I am using the R.matlab package.  To use `readMat()`, I don't believe I need the Matlab server open.  However, when I type in

```
r <- readMat("filename.mat")
```

I get the following error message:

```
Error in file(con, open = "rb") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(con, open = "rb") :
  cannot open file 'filename.mat': No such file or directory
```

I'm not sure what this means exactly.  I've tried saving this array into a *.txt file and then reading it in from the Matlab folder.  Then I thought maybe the *.mat object needed to be in the R folder.  That didn't work.

I have all packages needed (R.matlab, R.utils, R.oo), and I've opened the R.matlab library.  Do I need to be connected to the server to access the information?  I will try this next, but maybe there is another issue?

Comment: It means the file is not where you think it is. Use `getwd()` to see where R is looking. Then paste the path spec appropriate to your OS to that file name.

Comment: ok.  I setwd() to the folder for Matlab.  Why doesn't it automatically do so when you are working with Matlab?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set your working directory. Use `setwd("path/to/directory")`.